# create HTML snippet with jQuery for uinversal inclusion

Tags: jquery, code-snippets

I've to create a HTML/JS snippet which will be included in different WP installations as part of a post. I need some jQuery functions so I have to check if jQuery is already included and if it's not to load it. In some cases jQuery ist included in the footer an my snippet doesn't detect it. Could someone please look over this or give me some hint what I should have in mind when I want to create a universal HTML/JS snippet for inclusion.

```
<script>
 if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("head").append("<link>");
   var css = $("head").children(":last");
   css.attr({
     rel:  "stylesheet",
 type: "text/css",
     href: "http://www.domain.de/assets/style.css"
  });
 });
 </script>

 <div id="buy" style="width100%; float:left;">
 <a href="#">Jetzt kaufen</a>
 </div>
 <div style="display:none;width:100%; float:left;" id="logos">
<ul>

 <!--Ab hier editieren -->
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
 <!--Ab hier nicht mehr editieren-->
<ul>
 </div>
 <script>
 jQuery('#buy a').click( function() {
 jQuery('#logos').slideDown();
 } )
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload=function(){/* check for jQuery here */};
```

Comment: Removing all existing load events from the window object cannot be a good idea...

Comment: Yes, definitely. I meant to just take this event into consideration.